# Cannot call __subclass__ method inside format string expansion

Tags: python

I have this line of python code that returns a list of all classes that currently exist:

```
'a'.__class__.__mro__[1].__subclasses__()
```

Now I'd expect that this line would work in the same way:

```
'{0.__class__.__mro__[1].__subclasses__()}'.format('a')
```

but this gives me the error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'object' has no attribute '__subclasses__()'
```

Then again this line:

```
'{0.__class__.__mro__[1].__subclasses__}'.format('a')
```

prints out

```
'<built-in method __subclasses__ of type object at 0x9d1260>'
```

so the methods seems to be there but I can't call it for some reason. Can somebody explain this behavior to me?

Comment: Can you show us where you defined `a`?

Comment: 'a' is a string

Comment: Also this is not how you use string formatting

Answer (score 4):

`str.format` doesn't support arbitrary expressions in format strings. You can use indexing and attribute access, but not the function call operator (and even indexing is a little weird). Rather than trying to stuff all that in the format string itself, evaluate the expression outside and pass the result as an argument to `format`:

```
'{}'.format('a'.__class__.__mro__[1].__subclasses__())
```

Incidentally, this `__subclasses__` call doesn't give you a list of all subclasses that exist. It gives you a list of all *direct* subclasses of `object`. It doesn't include grandchild classes or further descendants.

Also, unless you're trying to perform some kind of sandbox escape or you've got some other weird constraint, you don't need to go through the whole `'a'.__class__.__mro__[1]` rigmarole just to refer to `object`.

Answer (score 0):

You were accessing an attribute `"__subclass__()"` (string!) instead of accessing `__subclass__` function then call it. i.e. the format string doesn't execute the function and returns the result in string.

To prove, try something instead:

```
>>> '{0.__class__.__mro__[1].__str__}'.format('a')
"<slot wrapper '__str__' of 'object' objects>"

>>> '{0.__class__.__mro__[1].__str__()}'.format('a')
AttributeError: type object 'object' has no attribute '__str__()'
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated, `str.format` does not allow calls.

If you really desire such behaviour, you could try out f-strings (if you are python 3.6+):

```py
>>> x = 'a'
>>> f'{x.__class__.__mro__[1].__subclasses__()}'
# output omitted
```